# Как правильно смержить ветки gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

Есть проект. У проекта локально есть две ветки разработки master и **dev**. В gitlab - четыре ветки у проекта
master, **dev**, fix и **seo**. Разработчики всегда работают с веткой **dev**, подключились сеошники и усердно начали работать с веткой **seo**. В итоге, за неделю, в gitlab появились две сильно различное между собой ветки.

Как правильно слить ветку seo с веткой dev чтобы в ней были все коммиты ветки seo?

Мне пришлось слить все изменения через `git diff ..seo`, но мне кажется это не совсем верно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Зайти в Gitlab веб интерфейс (так будет наглядней)
- Зайти в Branches
- Выбрать ветку, которую ходите мерджить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании реквеста, можно увидеть что и куда вливаете (вам нужно в данном случае **seo** и **dev**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внизу будет видны коммиты и изменения в каждом из файлов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Таким образом мержатся ветка что я выберу и master. А есть возможность мержить две любые ветки?

Comment: @Behmetev Конечно, __Change branches__ нажимаете, и выбираете любые ветки.